# Elementor Wordpress adding style to a shortcode element

Tags: wordpress, styles, shortcode, elementor

I've added a widget element (my account widget) to a page using a shortcode (there is an annoying bug when I use the widget).
and of course the element is missing the theme's style.
I've found one post about this, and how to resolve it, but I can't seem to understand WHERE do I find the html and css relevant to that element, and where to place them.
I would love to understand how it is done.

link to my page (you need to create an account to see it): https://rotemy12.sg-host.com/%d7%94%d7%97%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%9c%d7%99/

[link to the explanation I found](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/style-in-shortcode-2/)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to look into [how to edit templates/themes](https://wordpress.com/support/templates/).
It seems you will have to access files inside the `wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/`; there you should find a style.css, a function.php, (and a bunch of other files). You can edit style.css to customise styles to your liking: edit the style.css to [insert styling information for your widget](https://wordpress.com/support/css-basics/); you might need to look after [specific selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) depending on your theme.
Also please note that depending on the browser you are using, you should have developper's tools that will be useful to find out about parents' selectors [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) / [Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri20948/mac).

Comment: Thanks for your time.
I know all that,
and tried to find what are the relevant css tags and apply them to the widget in all sorts of ways. but it just didn't do anything

Comment: you might then want to address selectors higher up in the hierarchy something like: `html > body  main section div.sidebar widget.widget_class`

Comment: also: the dev console should give you all the styles applied to the element you wish to edit along with the file name and line number (element selection icon: then point and click on the element on the page)